# Angular + Electron + Chrome App

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-app, electron

I'm creating Electron app right now. The application which I'm using Angilar single page app in the renderer. It was used in Chrome Application in the past. Now my task is porting it to the electron. But the Chrome Application is still supported. As result I'm got a one code base for two applications. There is something like this in my Angular controllers (coffescript code):

```
angular.module("myApp")
.controller "myCtrl", () ->
    if typeof chrome is "undefined"
        {app} = require("electron").remote        
        appVersion = app.getVersion()
    else
        appVersion = chrome.runtime.getManifest().version
```

It is becoming more places with a code like this... It frightens me((
Probably I can wrap this in more abstract API or something else...
Do you have any ideas to make my code more beauty and modularity?